# Push Notification Not Shown to User for APPINVITE function in Facebook SDK for Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am using the AppInvite Dialog in Facebook SDK for Android.The problem is the end Users/Friends whom the AppInvite is sent to, don't receive the push notifications.
Although the Notification appears in the 'Notification Globe' and 'App Invites' Section of Facebook Native App.
The Users dont have the App installed.And the Applink url is working fine.

The app is running in production mode, have already added the users as TestUsers also.

The problem is just that the PushNotification is not shown to the User,although there is an entry in 'Notification Globe' 
Can somebody please help.

Comment: Have they _ever_ installed the app? Also, adding real users in a Test role for your app is not the same as creating Test Users https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users

Comment: @MingLi The User who sees the Notification in 'Notifcation Globe' had never installed the app.But the User who installed this app before, but had uninstalled it didnt see any notification, but there was an entry in App Invites section for him also.So What am i missing? What is the ideal way to test the notification in Development Mode.?

Comment: The invite will always show up in the App Invites section. If the user has installed the app previously, they may not get a push notification. The ideal way to test it is to use a new test user (using the link I sent above), who's never installed the app, and send them an invite.

Comment: I tested it with a new real user, who's never installed the app. And I tested it with a facebook test user. No Push Notifications, Why?

Answer (score 3):

From Facebook docs at [App invites overview](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/overview)

> If the person already has the app installed, they will not receive a push notification.

So make sure you uninstall the application from the device which receiving the invitation.

Comment: I tested it with a new real user, who's never installed the app. And I tested it with a facebook test user. No Push Notifications. This is not the correct answer.

Comment: Same problem on iOS here, but the request is really send, if you go in applications > applications invite in FB app you see the invite

Comment: I know, but without Push Notifications is Facebook App Invites not as powerful. On Facebook docs you can see, that the user gets a push notification. But it doesn't works for me.

https://scontent-ams2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/t39.2178-

Comment: I have encounter the same problem，have you solved it ?

Comment: same problem here, I am also not getting push notification

Comment: I have created two test accounts and tried with that but still no luck.

Comment: same problem here. any help would be appreciated !